# Get all subgraphs in JGraphT

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, jgrapht, subgraph

How can I get all possible subgraphs of a graph in JGraphT in a `List<MyGraph>` or `Set<MyGraph>` collection?
I've read the documentation of JGraphT, but I couldn't find anything to help me with that particular issue.

Comment: What exactly have you tried yourself? Provide a minimal example where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on whether the OP wants a [vertex-induced](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-InducedSubgraph.html) subgraph or an [edge-induced](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Edge-InducedSubgraph.html) subgraph. To create a vertex or edge induced subgraph in JGraphT, use the [AsSubgraph](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/graph/AsSubgraph.html) class. There is no method that will simply generate all possible subgraphs as this is a very uncommon procedure, but it is easy to implement yourself. Do notice that there are `2^n` possible vertex induced subgraphs, where `n` is the number of vertices. So the number of subgraphs is huge.

1. Create a List<Set> containing all possible subsets of vertices. This is called a powerset (there are many SO posts on how to generate a powerset)
2. For each set in your powerset, generate an induced subgraph using `AsSubgraph`.

Coarsely, the code looks like this:

```
//Initiate some graph. The vertex/edge type is irrelevant for this question
Graph<Integer,DefaultEdge> graph = new SimpleGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
...

//Generate powerset
List<Set<Integer>> powerSet = powerSet(graph.vertexSet());

//Create subgraphs:
for(Set<Integer> subset : powerSet)
    Graph<Integer,DefaultEdge> subGraph = new AsSubgraph(graph, subset);
```

To implement the powerSet function, many examples can be found on SO. To compute edge induced subgraphs, repeat the above but instead of graph.vertexSet() use graph.edgeSet();